# How to get ObjectID in Sails.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, sails.js

I am using  [**`sails-hook-orm-mongoose`**](https://github.com/mikermcneil/sails-hook-orm-mongoose) for my application to talk to MongoDB. I didn't find any official documentation or any clue out there in google, which can tell me how to get **ObjectID**.

In Express.js I used to get ObjectID like this:

`var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;`

How can I get **ObjectId** in my case?

Comment: Are you using mongodb native ORM?

Comment: No am using `sails-hook-orm-mongoose`

Comment: Isn't it just exactly the same require? Since that hook installs mongodb

Comment: Nope it is not work the usual way

Comment: @SiddharthaChowdhuryTry this
ObjectID = require('sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb').ObjectID;

Answer (score 0):

If you have `sails` set in `config/globals`, then you can access `mongoose` from anywhere.

So you can get the `ObjectId` like this: `sails.mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`.

Comment: I have sailsjs 1.4.0 and `sails.mongoose` is `undefined` for me.